# GNU texinfo directory search method?

Tags: info

Does `info` (GNU texinfo 4.13) have a default search path for finding a `dir` file?  Is it `/usr/share/info`?  Even though I don't have an `INFOPATH` variable set in my environment, it seems to use the `dir` file in the path above.

Relatedly, I have a script that sets up a directory with an alternate info directory structure.  It does set a valid `INFOPATH` environment variable but `info` seems not to use it as invocation simply gives a blank screen without any menu items.

Any guidance on how `info` progresses in searching the path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `info` does have a default value for `INFOPATH` compiled-in that it uses if you don't have `INFOPATH` set in your environment.  (Also, if your `INFOPATH` ends with a colon, then the default path is appended to your value.)

The default `DEFAULT_INFOPATH` is `.:/usr/local/info:/usr/info:/usr/local/lib/info:/usr/lib/info:/usr/local/gnu/info:/usr/local/gnu/lib/info:/usr/gnu/info:/usr/gnu/lib/info:/opt/gnu/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/share/lib/info:/usr/local/share/info:/usr/local/share/lib/info:/usr/gnu/lib/emacs/info:/usr/local/gnu/lib/emacs/info:/usr/local/lib/emacs/info:/usr/local/emacs/info` (but it can be changed by defining `DEFAULT_INFOPATH` while compiling `info`).

There's also a `INFODIR` variable that can be set while compiling `info`.  If set, it gets included in the path after the `INFOPATH` environment variable but before the `DEFAULT_INFOPATH`.

I don't know any way of asking your `info` program what values it was compiled with. (Although you can probably find the actual value of `DEFAULT_INFOPATH` with this command:)

```
strings `which info` | grep /info:
```

Answer (score 2):

The search order that `info` is taking to find files and nodes can be examined by invoking it with the various `--debug` options (`--debug -1` for all debug info).

For example

```
INFOPATH=: info --debug -1 _
```

will print out all the paths derived from `$PATH`, followed by all the compile-time defaults.